# Facebook Ads API throwing (Exception - #1487632) when updating an Ad Set's lifetime budget

Tags: facebook

I'm currently updating Ad Sets budget using the Facebook Ads API & I'm getting this 
**(Exception - #1487632) The number of times you can update the spend limit can not exceed the maximum number allowed.**
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here. I tried searching the Facebook error codes page(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/error-reference) but there's nothing here explaining this exception. I thought this might be because I'm exceeding the maximum number of times allowed for an budget update, however; I confirmed that it happens every second time I try to update the lifetime budget.

Comment: I'd suggest that you open a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/trending/

Answer (score 0):

changes to spend_limit is limited to 4 times an our (documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting/#adaccountlimit)